# FoxPro DOS (2.0): partial rebuild

Tags: foxpro

I have to save a really old FoxPro program.
The problem is that one source file (.prg) is corrupted, so i can't re-generate the executable compiling all.
Exist the way to re-compile just the file i've changed and left untouched the rest ? (I've used one option include/exclude in the "Project" menu but didn't it)
Thanks,

Comment: FoxPro has never offered an incremental compile feature. If you have a working EXE, you could buy Refox and decompile that to get clean source.

Comment: Look for a .BAK file with the same name as the .PRG.

Comment: Is it the program you need or just the data? You could grab the data from the dbf  files and rewrite the code in something a few decades more modern/

Comment: As i've explained before, the problem was with the source files. So, following the first suggestion, i've used Refox and i've recovered succesfully the file.